# How to calculate expenses excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an sheet where i calculate expenses and to make sure nothing was missed in my monthly report i added a new column called "actual balance", I need help to how to calculate this value properly.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaFvF.png)

for every expense excel need to check if the subtraction should be done for bank1 account or bank2 for it's latest value not just for the previous value in actual balance. i don't now if this can be done with just the formulas or should i code this in VBA to store the latest value of 'actual balance' for each account in variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make the lookup range use the same name as the bank column so you can use VLOOKuP to return the start amount.

Then use SUMIFS to return all the costs to that point:

```
=VLOOKUP(E4,$B$1:$C$2,2,FALSE)-SUMIFS($D$4:D4,$E$4:E4,E4)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help, i didn't think of vlookup